Using chaching_sha2_password but getting error: Plugin 'mysql_native_password' is not loaded
I just started working in mysql 8.4 and in my express backend I am connecting to mysql using mysql2. In the db I can see the user auth type is chaching_sha2_password, I made sure the dafault is also set to chaching_sha2_password but whenever I try to make a call with Postman I get this error: Plugin 'mysql_native_password' is not loaded. Where is mysql_native_password coming from? Below is my db config and connection
config.ts:
export const DB_CONFIG = {
    db: {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      connectTimeout: 60000,
      multipleStatements: true,
    },
    listPerPage: 10,
  };

db.ts:
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";
import { DB_CONFIG } from "../utils/config";

export default async function query(sql: any, params: any) {
  try {
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection(DB_CONFIG.db);
    const [results] = await connection.execute(sql, params);

    console.log("Database configuration:", connection);

    return Array.isArray(results) ? results : [results];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Database query error:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

I have tried setting default back to 'mysql_native_password' but that is not only less secure but brought it's own errors
I also tried uninstall and reinstall mysql2, nothing changes

Does mysql2 support chaching_sha2_password authentication in the first place?

I thought I saw that it was but now that I look further, I can't find confirmation on this

3 weeks ago a maintainer on the repo seems to indicate it is supported: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/discussions/3045

I can't see the linked github discussuon to indicate mysql2 supporting chaching_sha2_password authentication.

Looked around in the code and found this readme file:https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/lib/auth_plugins/caching_sha2_password.md Does this help? It seems to indicate you need to explicitly configure the use of the new auth plugin.

@Shadow that did remove the error, but brought along it's own issue. I'll count it as a win for now. Thank you!
